# Relation between two permutation metrics

Tags: metric-spaces, permutations, symmetric-groups

Consider the following two metrics on permutations of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$:

$d_{swap}(\sigma,\tau)$ is the minimum number of swaps of adjacent elements that are required to reach $\tau$ from $\sigma$ (or $\sigma$ from $\tau$). Alternatively, it is the number of *discordant pairs* for $\sigma$ and $\tau$. A pair of distinct elements $(x,y)$ is called a *discordant pair* for $\sigma$ and $\tau$ if $x$ and $y$ have different relative orderings in the two permutations. If I am not missing anything, $d_{swap}$ is identical to the [Kendell tau distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_distance).

$d_{sum}(\sigma, \tau)$ is given by $\sum_{i=1}^n |pos_{\sigma}(i) - pos_{\tau}(i)|$, where $pos_{\pi}$ indicates the position of $i$ in the permutation $\pi$.

I need to understand the relationship between these two metrics for another problem I am working on. In particular, I would like to know whether the following two conjectures I have are true:

- $d_{sum} \geq d_{swap}$
- there exists a constant $C < 1$, such that $d_{swap} \geq C \cdot d_{sum}$

While I am sure that these distances have been well studied, I did not manage to find the answer to these questions. If you know the answer or even any relevant literature feel free to help me out :)

Comment: Are your permutations in "line form" like if $n=4$ then $1432$ maps 1 and 3 to themselves and interchanges 2 and 4? [Or in cycle form or etc.]

Comment: They are in line form.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2492954

Comment: I had found that post. It is interesting, but does not appear to address any of my questions.

Comment: About the first conjecture $d_{sum} \ge d_{swap}$: For which small $n$ have you checked it? E.g. checked for $n\le 10$. It seems a program could be made to check it, I wonder when the checking time gets unmanagably long in terms of $n$. [That likely depends on software used.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was studied by Diaconis and Graham: [Spearman's Footrule as a Measure of Disarray](https://finmath.stanford.edu/%7Ecgates/PERSI/papers/77_04_spearmans.pdf).

What you call $d_{\text{swap}}$ they call $I$, and what you call $d_{\text{sum}}$ they call $D$. They show

$$I + T \leq D \leq 2 I$$

where $T$ is the number of transpositions needed to put the permutation in order, also called the reflection-length of a permutation. This language comes from the study of Coxeter Groups.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer! I should have mentioned that I ended up asking the question on Mathoverflow (see [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414495/relation-between-two-permutation-metrics)) where I received the same answer.